# How do I xcodebuild a static library with Bitcode enabled?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, bitcode

Xcode 7 introduces [Bitcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW3), which is some sort of LLVM intermediate binary that means Apple's servers can recompile my app for different architectures without my involvement.

At Lookback, I distribute a static archive framework with our library. It seems that when you build with anything but a "Build & Archive", bitcode is not actually emitted into my library, and anyone who links with my library in their app and tries to do a Build & Archive with Bitcode enabled will get one of two warnings:

- `ld: 'Lookback(Lookback.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.` (if lib is built with Xcode 6)
- `ld: warning: full bitcode bundle could not be generated because 'Lookback(Lookback.o)' was built only with bitcode marker. The library must be generated from Xcode archive build with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)` (if lib is built with Xcode 7 with a normal xcodebuild)

I have a build script that builds a device+simulator universal binary, so I can't use Build & Archive, but rather, I run `xcodebuild` from commandline from my script. How can I make `xcodebuild` generate a proper bitcode-enabled library?

Comment: HI @nevyn Im trying to get your SDK to compile in an app which uses bitcode. Is there a way?

Comment: @Stoff81 Sorry, I'm working on it. I need to get all my dependencies working with Bitcode first, and it's quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Bitcode is a compile-time feature (not a link-time feature) which means that every .o file should contain an extra section called __bitcode when built with bitcode. You can confirm whether your binary is bitcode-compatible by running `otool -l (my .o or .a file) | grep __LLVM`.

When you build normally, Xcode adds the build flag `-fembed-bitcode-marker` to any clang invocation. This seems to be some sort of 'this is where bitcode would go, if bitcode was enabled' thing, and doesn't actually enable bitcode.

When you "Build & Archive", this flag is replaced by `-fembed-bitcode`, which really does build a Bitcode-enabled binary.

There seems to be two ways to make `xcodebuild` use `-fembed-bitcode`:

- Use the 'archive' action, as in `xcodebuild -target LookbackSDK archive` instead of `xcodebuild -target LookbackSDK build`. This has the side-effect of putting binaries in your Xcode Organizer instead of the `build/` folder, though you can work around that by using `-exportArchive -archivePath ./build` (thanks [@JensAyton](https://twitter.com/jensayton/status/622349580986916864))
- Force usage of the flag by adding Other C Flags with `OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"`. Your `xcodebuild` invocation would look something like `xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" -target LookbackSDK build`.

The latter is what I chose so that I don't have to change my build system, but it will generate warnings for every file, since now both `-fembed-bitcode-marker` and `-fembed-bitcode` are sent to clang. Luckilly the latter wins, generating a Bitcode-enabled library!

#### Resources

- [Apple DevForums: Bitcode and Assembly?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/7038)
- [SO: iOS library to BitCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233395/ios-library-to-bitcode)

Comment: FWIW, you can get rid of the warning about `-fembed-bitcode-marker` being ignored by adding `-Qunused-arguments` as well.

Comment: which exportFormat do use for a xcodebuild of a framework? Only "ipa", "pkg" and "app" seems to be defined (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html).

Comment: @nevyn Still could not build my main app which has the custom framework file which in turn contains a build script with the above mentioned flag.

Comment: otool -l (my .o or .a file). Do you mean otool -l (my .o or .a file) | grep __bitcode ?

Comment: @MikeM no actually `otool -l myfile.o | grep __LLVM`, because there will be a __bitcode segment even if there's only bitcode marker in there instead of real bitcode.

Comment: @nevyn I actually tried compiling a library without this flag (not an XCode project but a C library, using clang) and there was no such section until I added the flag. Also, when doing that there is no guarantee that there will the an OTHER_CFLAGS variable in the make script and there might be a need to put the argument in the CFLAGS.

Comment: @MikeM `OTHER_CFLAGS` is an Xcode setting, not a clang/gcc setting. Setting `OTHER_CFLAGS` won't do anything in a `Makefile`, you're supposed to set it in the Xcode UI or an xcconfig file. In addition, it's Xcode that adds `-fembed-bitcode-marker`, so if you compile with clang manually without that flag, you won't even get the bitcode markers.

Comment: i have a bash script that builds a fat framework and adding the OTHER_CFLAGS doesn't produce a framework with bitcode, any tips?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech not without more context; post a separate question with the relevant parts of the bash script source?

Comment: @nevyn the bash script: https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/115398/Script-for-iOS-Universal-Framework-compi

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore for .a static library archives. Now, `otool -l` seems to just show `mylib.a(xxx.c.o): is an LLVM bit-code file`.

Comment: Conceptually, since static libraries have hardcoded list of architectures, doesn't it conflict with the idea of bitcode? That Apple can build for new architectures on the fly?

Comment: worked a treat (option 2) on Xcode 9.4.1 (objc project).

Answer (score 44):

With Xcode 8, I couldn't get `OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"` to work. I kept running into something along the lines of `was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build` when I tried to create an Archive build of an app containing my static framework.

What I was really looking for was this:

```
BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode
```

I'm actually using a Run Script inside of an aggregate target, the full xcodebuild line looks like this (just for reference):

`xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build`

Comment: +1, the `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode` method seems to be preferred, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34965178/72176) too.

Comment: This also fixed my issue whereas the default answer doesn't anymore.

Comment: Life saver! Thank you!

Comment: +1. Accepted answer didn't work for me, but including `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Once you add bitcode support for the static lib, it won't be compatible with Xcode 6. The app won't archive.

I would like to clearly mention the setting for bitcode as @nevyn's answer confused me a little.

Go to Build settings, search for "custom compiler flags". Add `-fembed-bitcode`. This will build your lib with bitcode.

Answer (score 7):

Select project
On Build Settings -> Other C flags, set Debug to -fembed-bitcode-marker and Release to -fembed-bitcode

On Build Settings, click on the + sign at the top to add a user-defined build setting with the name BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE, and set Debug to marker, Release to bitcode

Edit schema as Release 
Then click the desired library.  A file and get the build path.
Get the library form Release folder.