# ios zbar bit code enabled

Tags: ios, zbar, bitcode

I am look for "libzbar.a" (zbar compiled library) with BitCode enabled for armv7, armv7s, arm64 architechtures
I tried downloading the zbar xcode project and enabling Bitcode and compiling the library
I also tried other methods such as the one provided in the link :
[How do I xcodebuild a static library with Bitcode enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486232/how-do-i-xcodebuild-a-static-library-with-bitcode-enabled)
with no success

the linker error:
...ibzbar.a(ZBarCaptureReader.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed this great article by saturngod and successfully re-compiled "libzbar.a" with full support for Bitcode:
http://www.saturngod.net/articles/enable-bitcode-in-library-file/

Comment: Thanks, to summarize: The trick was putting -fembed-bitcode in other C flags. Also don't forget since the ZBar project is quite old setting the standard architectures. Then create a fat library as needed.

Answer (score 3):

The binary with source code, bitcode enabled
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-ziC02v2vGiTENJWGdacXVxUEE