# xcode project build successfully but when archiving: bitcode bundle could

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

My XCode project was generated by Unity so I was able to build the project without errors.

But when I try to archive it for ad hoc, I get this:

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/myuser/Desktop/device3/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/AdmobPlugin.a(UnityEncoder.o)'
>   was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for
>   bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for
>   architecture arm64

What is needed in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486232/how-do-i-xcodebuild-a-static-library-with-bitcode-enabled maybe useful

Answer (score 46, accepted):

AdmobPlugin.a does not support bitcode try updating that library if its still showing this error you can disable bitcode from your Xcode project goto target setting -> Enable bitcode = NO.

Comment: Will this negatively affect the other code? Maybe there are libraries that use bitcode?

Comment: It failed when I am trying to export the app from archive for generating ipa file.

Answer (score 6):

Just got this error message. Went to Target -> Settings -> Enable Bitcode = NO
Works perfectly, No issues.

Answer (score 3):

On Build Settings -> Other C flags, set Debug to -fembed-bitcode-marker, and Release to -fembed-bitcode. Make sure that is set for your project, and not the targets. More details check [here](https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the distinction between project and targets. Could you please elaborate?