# Enabling Bitcode in dynamic framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, bitcode

I am currently building a dynamic framework for iOS and tvOS. Therefor I lipo simulator and device binaries to one fat library via script. Bitcode is enabled in Build Settings, as you can see here:

[image: Build Settings]

I verified the library after creation with otool. Bitcode is definitely enabled.
When I now try to add this library to my Main App via Cocoapod and validate this App with Archive -> Validate, I am getting the following error message:

[image: XCode error]

[image: Build Settings Demo App]

Somebody has a clue why the AppStore is complaining?

Comment: It's difficult to see what target that `ENABLE_BITCODE=YES` is affecting with all the names redacted.  Why not set it at the project level instead?

Comment: Same error if I enable it on project level @trojanfoe

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296331/299924) is the issue.  It looks like `lipo` might be stripping-out the bitcode. Try keeping it simple.  Generate the framework with no `lipo` script and have the app target depend on the framework so it embeds it within the bundle and see where that gets you.

Comment: But I verified the framework which was created by lipo with otool. And otool showed that bitcode is inside the framework... And how can I have a framework with device and simulator binaries inside without using lipo?

Comment: Well the approach would be rather than keeping the framework and app projects separate, put them together in the same workspace and see if that makes it work.  I assume your end-goal is to the provide the framework as a deliverable to other projects, but I am trying to see if it works in a simple manner first.

Comment: I just tried it without the lipo command. I created my framework and checked it with otool... Everything fine. After that tried to upload to app store and got the same error again :/ @trojanfoe

Comment: Hmmm, not sure then :-|

Comment: Ok, if I add both in one workspace and add the framework directly to my main App, I can upload it without a problem... So it only not works if I add my framework via Cocoapods...

Comment: If you add your framework via CocoaPods then your must enable bitcode on Pods project

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov I also tried that. Same error...