# bitcode bundle could not be generated because iOS Charts

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-charts, bitcode

I make app with 3d library [iOS-Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts). But I get the error **bitcode bundle could not be generated because was built without full bitcode.** from today widget. I installed it with help Carthage and I did all the instructions. I do not know how can I fix it? I made the following screenshot from today widget target.
[image]

Comment: Try to disable ENABLE_BITCODE flag in build settings tab if your app do not need to support bitcode.

Comment: @Alexsander Please check [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233395/ios-library-to-bitcode) and see if adding the `-fembed-bitcode` flag in build settings works for you.

Comment: @DavidCheung it helped me. You may to write it like an answer.

Comment: @Alexsander Done, please check.

Comment: Same problem for me.  The only way I could compile was by disabling "ENABLE BITCODE" flag in build settings.  The problem happened when I temporarily disabled bitcode to get better debugging for a crash on an ad-hoc install.  Now, it seems the system is stuck with this message relating to some "SparkUI.o" file and I cannot use bitcode anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this SO thread and see if adding the -fembed-bitcode flag in build settings works for you.

[iOS library to BitCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233395/ios-library-to-bitcode)

Answer (score 12):

Please try to change Enable Bitcode to No in Build Settings.

[image]

Comment: This does not provide a solution to archiving with bitcode enabled.

Answer (score 10):

I found one possible cause is if you are using CocoaPods and the dependencies are not being compiled using bitcode.

I added this to my `Podfile` to fix it.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE'] = 'bitcode'
    config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
  end
end
```

Comment: I suspect this is the case for me but Cocoapods are so horrible i can't bring myself to reinstall because it will cause 2000+ compile errors and take days to sort through.  So, I am just turning off bitcode... I hate Cocoapods.