# iOS Framework on device bitcode not included

Tags: ios, alamofire, ios-frameworks

I am developing static library for iOS, in which I am using Alamofire. When I try to build for release for simulator, everything is ok, however when I try to build it for device (release or debug) I get following problem:

```
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/PathToMyLibraryProducts/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture armv7
```

My framework has enabled bitcode, and it is fat framework (build for device and simulator). How can I resolve that?

Comment: Running directly on device?

Comment: It is when I build for 'Generic Device', when I build for real device there is only a little bit different message - `bitcode ... for architecure amd64`

Comment: did you solved this issue??? how to ensure bitcode support

Answer (score 5):

## If you are using cocoapods-binary with cocoapods

This error will appear since cocoapods-binary won't generate frameworks with bitcode enabled unless you specifically indicate that by using this key in your `Podfile`:

`enable_bitcode_for_prebuilt_frameworks`

This is how your Podfile will look:

```
plugin 'cocoapods-binary'

platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!
enable_bitcode_for_prebuilt_frameworks!
all_binary!

target 'ProjectName' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
end
```

Comment: getting Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `enable_bitcode_for_prebuilt_frameworks!'

Comment: @ShubhamGoel you have to run `gem install cocoapods-binary` first

Answer (score 1):

I think, `bitcode` is not enabled while you are building for `Generic Device`. So do the following:

1. Under `pods.xcodeproj`, select all pods target.
2. Navigate under `Build Settings` and make sure that all your
   "Pods" > "Build Settings" > "Build Active Architecture Only" is set
   to "NO".
3. Enable `Bitcode` set to `YES`
4. Then, tap on project target, and follow the Step 2 and 3
5. Clean the build and make `Archive`

Comment: After that, when Archive i get `ld: -reexport_framework and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together`. No changes for run on device.

Comment: Have you clean the build? and also delete DeviredData folder too.

Comment: Ok, I am able to archive app which is using my framework. But  I am still not able to run it on device and can not generate fat library

Comment: What error are you receiving while running on device?

Comment: The same I mentioned in answer - `ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/PathToMyLibraryProducts/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture armv64`

Comment: Please check this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233395/ios-library-to-bitcode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666247/bitcode-bundle-could-not-be-generated-because-ios-charts

Comment: already tried this, and also tried this https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9 - nothing changed. Still can not run app on device

Comment: @TomaszCzura, Were you able to resolve the issue, if yes can you share the solution? I am facing the same issue. Did go through all the links mentioned but failed.

Comment: Did you solved it?? It is nightmare for us and it is real issue... Cant solve for 5 days

Answer (score 1):

Found this discussion which may be [relevant](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/835)

In summary the following setting is needed:
BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode for Release builds and BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=marker for Debug builds

Hope that helps.

Kind regards,
Mukund

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your pod file, It will enable Bitcode for all the framework.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```