# Xcode 7 Fails to Archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, clang, xcode7

I am using Xcode 7.3.1.

My project runs perfectly on both iOS Simulator as well as my own iPhone. However, when archiving my project, I get the warnings and errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/parthsaxena/Desktop/Vantage/Vantage/Vantage/TextFieldEffects/TextFieldEffects.framework/TextFieldEffects, file was built for arm64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/parthsaxena/Desktop/Vantage/Vantage/Vantage/TextFieldEffects/TextFieldEffects.framework/TextFieldEffects

ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/parthsaxena/Desktop/Vantage/Vantage/Pods/FirebaseAppIndexing/Frameworks/FirebaseAppIndexing.framework/FirebaseAppIndexing(FIRAppIndexing.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

You may have noticed that I am using both the Firebase and TextFieldEffects frameworks in my project.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: see this https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9#.ubmzv16t2

Comment: and this also once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233395/ios-library-to-bitcode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios-9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your library was compiled without bitcode, but the bitcode option is enabled in your project settings. Say NO to Enable Bitcode in your target Build Settings and the Library Build Settings to remove the warnings.

For those wondering if enabling bitcode is required:

Note: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't support bitcode at the moment (the situation should change in a short time). You should set `Build Settings` -> `Enable Bitcode` to **NO**.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because i didn't have enough free space on my mac