# Error before archive app IOS Swift3

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

H im trying to publish my app in IOS, to make this try to generate archive:
but show me:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Showing All Errors Only

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/dortiz/Documents/IOS/ProcIOS/Pods/MOCA/libMOCALib.a(Inbox.o)'
>   was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for
>   bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for
>   architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation) Build failed    25/04/17, 3:53 p.m.

I try to fix error adding

> -fembed-bitcode

In flags c and c++

Comment: Ok so did you read the error message? Did you perform some research?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the app compile and works, but in archive show me this error,  I don't understand why and I try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233395/ios-library-to-bitcode but doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to clean the project/build folder before?

Comment: Yes, same error :(

Comment: try to disable bitcode

Comment: how I can disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Targets > Build Settings. Then, search for "bitcode". Set the `Enable Bitcode` to "NO".