# Bitrise, Xcode9 (beta6): bitcode bundle could not be generated

Tags: ios, xcode9, eureka-forms, bitrise

One of the frameworks I use fails to get built with Bitrise with Xcode9beta stack. I must point out that this is Bitrise-specific issue. Or either, Bitrise/Eureka issue. Eureka is a particular instance of third-party framework.

Project is built well on the local machine, no bitcode-related issues whatsoever. But whenever I run CI, I get that typical log:

```
❌  ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '.../Frameworks/Eureka.framework/Eureka' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '.../Frameworks/Eureka.framework/Eureka' for architecture armv7

❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I followed these guidelines:
[iOS library to BitCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233395/ios-library-to-bitcode)

Flag is set.

[image: Bitcode]

I have also tried similar settings for head project/target, to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a dependency (version) issue:

```
... was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated ...
```

Might be enough to just upgrade the eureka dependency.

Another thing is that Xcode 9 (GM) is also available now, that alone might help.

Edit: a third option; you might have to disable Bitcode in the Xcode / xcodebuild command, as the default changed in Xcode 9 for some configs. See e.g. https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/xcode-archive-significantly-slower-on-xcode-9-0-x-stack-compared-to-xcode-8-3-x-stack/2708/2?u=viktorbenei

Without more log / info unfortunately it's quite hard to say with certainty.

If neither would help, you can also create an issue report at https://discuss.bitrise.io/c/issues/build-issues and the bitrise team will look into it ;)

Comment: Downloaded GM, builds well locally, but fails with bitrise. Eureka dependency is up to date. I believe I'd have to just wait for official Eureka update, for the one which is available publicly is basically a 'beta', with no stable xcode9 support. Thanks for your assistance nonetheless.