# When publishing a project (swift 4.2) in the AppStore, an error occurs when linking the libPrinterSDK library.a

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

All kind time of day. The project on Swift uses the SDK for blueTouth printer Mini Thermal Printer POS-5805DD. The libPrinterSDK library (included with the printer) has been added to the root of the project.a and the PrinterSDK header file.h, header-file is connected via bridge, when you run the project on a real device-everything works correctly, no errors occur. But when you try to build a project to upload to the AppStore, at the very end when linovke libprintersdk library.a an error appears:

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/ivan/Documents/MyProject/PrinterSDK/libPrinterSDK.a
>   (GCDAsyncSocket.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files
>   and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or
>   Install build file
>   '/Users/ivan/Documents/MyProject/PrinterSDK/libPrinterSDK.a' for
>   architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If there is any experience of building a project with libPrinterSDK files.a and PrinterSDK.h, I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure your project has turn Enable Bitcode off yet, if not, try to set No like this image below and Archive project again.
If it doesn't work, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233395/ios-library-to-bitcode)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, disabled this option and everything compiled. Not quite understood just how the published application can be affected by the lack of bitcode. 
What does it mean: ...to take advantage of hardware, software or compiler changes... In Apple commentary. :)

Comment: Found a useful discussion on bitcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722606/what-does-enable-bitcode-do-in-xcode-7